# How to display geom_text as millions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scale

Typically to display axis values in different scales in ggplot2 we can use the following:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))
```

How can the same be done for geom_text labels? With commas we would do the following

```
p + geom_text(aes(y = y_val, x = x_val, label = scales::comma(value)))
```

Is there a function analogous to comma for millions (ex: 100M)?

Comment: Does `p + geom_text(aes(y = y_val, x = x_val, label = scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6)(value))) ` work? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: So i actually tried the above and it seems the extra parenthesis `(value)` were not appreciated. I was hoping for a simple `comma` like function but sans that the above does work if applied to the dataframe and called as a new variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "not appreciated" Do you have a column named "value" in your data.frame? If not, what's the name of the column that has the value that you want to use as the text label? The `value` is just whatever column name you like.

Comment: The `unit_format` function returns a function. you can name it like `mill <-  scales::unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6)` and then call `mill(c(1e6, 25e5))` or use that in your aes: `label = mill(value)` like you would any other function.

Comment: Yeah, I see how that works, naming the output of `unit_format` is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `paste` within `geom_text` in a similar way to accomplish what you are asking?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


example_data <- tibble(
  foo = c(1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5500000),
  bar = c(1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5500000)
)

ggplot(example_data, aes(x = foo, y = bar)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(foo / 1e6, 1), "M")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>